# С помощью JS я хотела убрать элемент из формы при нажатии на radiobutton, но что-то пошло не так

Tags: javascript, radiobutton

**Функция которую я использую:**

```
function signUpUserType(myRadio) {

    currentValue = myRadio.value;
    alert(currentValue);
    if(currentValue==1)
    {
        document.getElementById("ClassInput").style.display = "none";
    }
    else { 
        if (currentValue==2){

            document.getElementById("ClassInput").style.display = "none";   

        } else (currentValue==3){

            document.getElementById("ClassInput").style.visibility = "visible";
        }
    }
}
```

**Форма:**

```
    <label>
        <input type="radio" id="teacher-role" name="role" value="1" checked  onclick="signUpUserType(this);">
        <label for="radioTeach">Учитель</label>

        <input type="radio" id="curator-role" name="role" value="2" checked onclick="signUpUserType(this);">
        <label for="radioCur">Куратор</label>

        <input type="radio" id="student-role" name="role" value="3" checked onclick="signUpUserType(this);">
        <label for="radioStud">Ученик</label> 
    </label>
```

Никакую ошибку не выдает, но и код не работает.

[image: "Элемент с id="ClassInput"]

[image: Вот изображение самой формы и нужно убрать форму выборки класса.]

Comment: Выложите больше кода, я не вижу элементов с id ClassInput

Comment: @Denis640Kb добавила. Спасибо за замечание

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Igor правильно ответил. С более удобным и коротким вариантом, но если Вы ещё планируете манипуляция с полем id="ClassInput"

На всякий случай пример:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    function signUpUserType(myRadio) {
        currentValue = myRadio.value;
        if(currentValue==1) {
            document.getElementById("ClassInput").style.display = "none";
        } else if (currentValue==2){

                document.getElementById("ClassInput").style.display = "none";

        } else if (currentValue==3){

                document.getElementById("ClassInput").style.display = 'block';

        }
    }

</script>
<label>
    <input type="radio" id="teacher-role" name="role" value="1" checked  onclick="signUpUserType(this);">
    <label for="radioTeach">Учитель</label>

    <input type="radio" id="curator-role" name="role" value="2" checked onclick="signUpUserType(this);">
    <label for="radioCur">Куратор</label>

    <input type="radio" id="student-role" name="role" value="3" checked onclick="signUpUserType(this);">
    <label for="radioStud">Ученик</label>
</label>
<div id="ClassInput">sakfjlsjf</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое)

Answer (score 2):

В Вашем коде несимметричное показывание/убирание элемента.

```
document.getElementById("ClassInput").style.display = 
  (currentValue == 3)? "block" : "none";
```

Comment: @ЗаринаЛибон Да, это влияет на отображение элемента.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое))

Comment: @ЗаринаЛибон На здоровье. Успехов!

Answer (score -1):

Я не вижу работающего примера, не могу сказать как будет правильно, но если вы планируете элементом несколько раз пользоваться, получайте его как переменную, так намного удобнее, сложнее потеряться в коде, а также не нужно заново получать элемент(что сделает вашу программу быстрее)

```js
function signUpUserType(myRadio) {

 currentValue = myRadio.value;
 let classInput = document.getElementById("ClassInput");
 console.log(currentValue);
 
 if (currentValue == 1) {
  classInput.style.display = "none";
 } else if (currentValue == 2) { 
  classInput.style.display = "block";   
 } else if (currentValue == 3) {
  classInput.style.visibility = "visible";
 }

}
```

```css
#ClassInput {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<label>
    <input type="radio" id="teacher-role" name="role" value="1" checked  onclick="signUpUserType(this);">
    <label for="radioTeach">Учитель</label>

    <input type="radio" id="curator-role" name="role" value="2" checked onclick="signUpUserType(this);">
    <label for="radioCur">Куратор</label>

    <input type="radio" id="student-role" name="role" value="3" checked onclick="signUpUserType(this);">
    <label for="radioStud">Ученик</label> 
</label>

<div id="ClassInput">
</div>
```